# How to create a symbolic link that links one file into every subdirectory including children

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I mistakenly asked this question on StackOverflow, and they suggested I ask it here instead.

I've read a lot of the other posts here, and they all seem to be answered successfully, but I just can't follow along. I'm still very new, and I don't want to try the trial and error approach, because I'm not sure if I'll be able to fix it. Here's where I am.

I have a file named "php.ini" that's in the root web folder of my host. I need this folder to also be in every single folder and subfolder on the server. The host suggested "creating a symbolic link in the subfolders" and that was the extent of their help. I asked how and they told me to google it. So I did.. and I'm lost. So far I have this:

```
ln -s /path/to/htdocs/php.ini LINK-NAME
```

But I'm not actually sure if this is right, and I'm not sure what the `LINK-NAME` is supposed to be, or what it does. Also, I don't know if this will create the link in every folder and subfolder? Since I'm supposed to use SSH to enter this command, I want to make sure I have it right before I try. I'm sorry if this is very basic knowledge (noob) question, all my searches just give an example and none of them explain what they do!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can't you experiment a little? Just try the command in some *test* directory with subdirectories. You won't solve the problem completely but hopefully "what the `LINK-NAME` is supposed to be" and "if this will create the link in every folder and subfolder" will no longer be mysteries. Plus `man ln` is your friend. "Making sure you have it right before you try" won't get you far in Linux. :) Or maybe you lack knowledge on how to create a test directory and tidy the mess you may cause there? Are these commands familiar: `mkdir`, `cd`, `cp`, `rm`, rmdir`? I'm not judging; just asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could `find` every directory in some path

```
find path -type d
```

and have find execute `-exec` (or `-execdir` is supposed to be more secure) `ln` (with `-v` for verbose) on it (assuming the full path you want to link to is `/path/to/htdocs/php.ini`)

```
find path -type d -execdir ln -v -s /path/to/htdocs/php.ini '{}' ';'
```

Or instead of using `-exec` or `-execdir` you could pipe find's output to `xargs` (null separated output might be helpful, `-print0` / `-0`), or use in a bash/sh script, etc...

---

But first, you might want to check if there are already any php.ini files in there, with

```
find path -name php.ini
```

or if you've made a bunch of new php.ini links and want to check what they actually point to, use

```
find path -name php.ini -execdir readlink '{}' ';'
```

or if you make a mistake creating a ton of bad php.ini files, you can delete them with

```
find path -name php.ini -delete
```